# Python - multiple series of JSON data

Tags: python, json, parsing

```
   [
   {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DD741HcHii8vq4fzPH58UDU7virAvtYyJf",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -9.00000000,
    "fee" : -1.00000000,
    "confirmations" : 316,
    "blockhash" : "9546b8d336c74222040b85a0a760c4c3dc4d5b744e0072fc1551f56f20472739",
    "blockindex" : 31,
    "blocktime" : 1394208201,
    "txid" : "45f80847a45eab62189759eb9da30f40052c581ea06ca062ac155bbf563b907d",
    "time" : 1394208153,
    "timereceived" : 1394208153
    },
    {
    "account" : "",
    "address" : "DD741HcHii8vq4fzPH58UDU7virAvtYyJf",
    "category" : "send",
    "amount" : -0.04063000,
    "fee" : -2.00000000,
    "confirmations" : 313,
    "blockhash" : "27cd2b1f380a651f78f83ef4deaaaf6a220028fe09b4219207ad5efecc69a29f",
    "blockindex" : 7,
    "blocktime" : 1394208392,
    "txid" : "af48a278c3559f1c36a2fccda42ba35cc62c2083fa5959a567f6b4d4a4a594a7",
    "time" : 1394208388,
    "timereceived" : 1394208388
    }
    ]
```

I have some data that is being put it a file called text.json

How am I able to read this?

I've tried parsing it as normal JSON but get the error:

```
    "list indices must be integer, not str"
```

And, if I do find a way of reading it can I do something like this:

```
getAmountOfRecords("blockindex")
JSON.parse[blockindex[0]] (returning 31)
JSON.parse[blockindex[1]] (returning 7)
```

Thanks :)

EDIT:

My code is:

```
import os
import json
from pprint import pprint

os.system("dogecoind listtransactons > text.json")
with open('text.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
input = raw_input('Enter a getter\n')
local = data[input]
print local;
```

Traceback is:

```
File "th.py", line 12, in <module>
local = data[input]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: What parser are you using? I used the stock one for Python (just `import json`) and it worked...

Comment: `import json` and then `with open('text.json') as f: my_json = json.load(f)`

Comment: That wouldn't give that error. Please show the exact command that gives the error, plus the traceback.

Comment: I have updated my OP with my exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with parsing, but with accessing the parsed data. Your data is a list of dicts. Therefore, you cannot access it with string keys directly.  `data['blockindex']` does not exist: only `data[0]['blockindex']`, `data[1]['blockindex']`, and so on.

Comment: Oh that's fantastic. By the way data[0][blockindex] worked just fine without the quotes. Am I able to see how many records of 'blockindex' there are?

Comment: Got it, print len(data)